# resize div with image on page load and window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

The header of http://bm-translations.de changes its height depending on window width but sometimes when I load the page it looks like that:
[image]

Thats the code:

```
//navheader responsive height   
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    $("#banner").css("height",$('#navheader').height()+30);
}).trigger('resize'); //on page load
```

How to optimize it?

**As suggested in comments I tried to set CSS calc instead, but without any result. What am I doing wrong?**

I set the parent `#navigation` to `height:100%` and `#banner` to

```
height: -moz-calc(100% + 30px);
height: -webkit-calc(100% + 30px);
height: calc(100% + 30px);
```

Comment: Take a look at CSS `calc`

Comment: Also you could use `requestAnimationFrame` or `debounce`

Comment: Doesn´t this increase the height on every resize ? Is this really what you want ?

Comment: @Doomenik have a look at the page and try with resizing. Its working perfectly as expected. It adds 30px to the height, as needed. Just sometimes it starts that weird.

Comment: Ok just wondered, there is no exception. I dont see there a reason for an event binding. You could increase it in the definition or just do the same in  
`$(window).load(function(){ //Height increase }); `.. This should also fix this bug.

Comment: Why can't you just remove the ´height: 50px;´ from ´.navbar-brand´?

Comment: The problem is you set with this event the height to `height + 30px`. Sometimes the event fires before everything is finished which means your banner has a height of 0. `0+30 = 30px` which then results as the bug you have. With window.load you can avoid that this happens.

Comment: the last both: you are right. 
@JonasGiuro sometimes you cannot see the wood for the trees.

But I am still wondering how to fix that resizing problem with calc. Can you have a look at my updated question?

Comment: I don't understand what the desired result is. To me, if you remove the fixed height from .navbar-brand, you can completely get rid of the js setting the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` instead of just run `$(window).trigger('resize')` at the bottom of the page, as follows:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
     $(window).trigger('resize');
})
```

As you can see from the following link:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." Code
>   included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page
>   Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.
>   Code included inside `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })`
>   will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

As you have images in navigation, you should wait the full page load for correct `$('#navheader').height()` detection.